# Table with selectable items in Access 2003

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I need to create a form in which user can select one item from the table. Then user can click on button so data in selected row can be used in next step. I am unable to find optimal solution. 
First, I don't know how to make such view/table with selectable items. Second, I don't know how to gather data from selected row. I am totally new in MS Access 2003 and VBA, maybe someone has already solved such issue or know how to do this... Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some time I asked my colleague how they solved this. In fact it's just a little trick. All you need to do is load data into textbox(es). So each time user clicks on some row, data are loaded. And then, when he clicks on button to proceed on next step, you got it! Nice in textbox(es). :) Can be handy...

Answer (score 0):

It is probably best to start with a sample database and a tutorial. The Northwind Sample database ships with Access 2003 : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824265, it is quite informative, even if the code is a little odd at times. It is quite a long run-up from where you are at the moment.

Comment: I shudder to think what the results are for anyone starting from the sample databases or the templates that ship with Access. They implement a whole host of WORST PRACTICES involving Access and should not be used as examples by anyone who doesn't understand which parts to completely disregard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the click around and work it out type, I would suggest first that you go to the forms tab, click the new button, choose form wizard and select a table.

Select all columns to add to your new form and finish the wizard. Then, right click it, click Form Design, and edit from there.

Otherwise maybe you need a good book because you have a bit of a curve ahead!

Good luck!